# Get back lost picture after flashing ROM

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, data-recovery, photos

I'm guessing I know the answer to this but still wanted to ask. I picture got deleted and I would like it back. It was taken with the stock android camera. I flashed a new ROM and that's how it got deleted. It was the picture for the Owner profile/user/account. Any way to get it back?

Comment: Try  [Undelete App from the PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.undelete&referrer=utm_source%3DAndroidPIT%26utm_medium%3DAndroidPIT%26utm_campaign%3DAndroidPIT). If you are lucky you may see it

Comment: @beeshyams is there a way to view contents of a TWRP backup without reflashing it to the whole phone?

Comment: Sorry.. Not that i know of

Comment: @Celeritas TWRP backups are supposedly generated with `tar` (they're actually .tar or .tar.gz files) - try unpacking with that in mind. It might not help if you don't know what content to look for in the extracted content, though.

Comment: @AndyYan no tar for me, only .win and .md5

Comment: @Celeritas I mean they're .tar in nature - try modifying their extension to .tar.

Comment: @Celeritas Yes, you can view nandroids with an app called Nandroid Manager. It's free on Google Play.