# Does the user profile picture get synced anywhere?

Tags: sync, photos, profiles

In Android Marshmallow, does the user profile picture get synced anywhere? If yes, where can I find it, somewhere in G+ maybe? By profile picture I mean this (image copied from http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/android-5-0-lollipop-user-profile-photo-t2939546)

[image: arrow pointing to profile picture]

Comment: Open Google+. Goto account settings then Contacts and click keep contacts up to date. That should change the blue icon to your G+ profile pic. Sync may not happen immediately

Comment: @beeshyams I mean from the opposite direction, I'm trying to see if a lost picture was synced so I can retrieve it http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/158316/get-back-lost-picture-after-flashing-rom I'm not sure if it synced to G+ (as it's possible to have a different account profile picture than a G+ profile picture) but was wondering if it synced somewhere?

Comment: Not sure if it syncs anywhere, but it's set via Settings - Users, it is a Contact photo for any Users you may have setup for your device.  You can select any photos that you have on your device, Google Drive, Google Photos, etc.

Comment: @RMarkwald I have flashed ROMs before and some of the contact photos synced (automatically) I'm not sure what determines it.